# Storing files locally in Node Webkit App

Tags: node-webkit

Folks:

I'm creating an app using Node Webkit. The purpose of this app is to display images and pdfs. The app needs to download those files from a central repository, and cache them locally. When the app runs offline, the files should still be available, and displayed.

On the face of it, this sounds like appcache is the answer - and that indeed is where I was heading when this was a pure webapp in a browser. However, now I've discovered node-webkit, and here we are.

node-webkit's GitHub wiki states:
"However, application cache is designed for browser use, for apps using node-webkit, it's less useful than the other two method, read HTML5 Application Cache if you want to use it."

But doesn't say *why*.

I've also researched node.js filesystem - but that seems like a whole magnitude of complexity above what I need.

Can anyone point me in a sensible direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the nature of App Cache itself.

You specify a manifest file that lists all the static assets required for your app to run offline. You don't have any programmatic access to the cache to add and remove files via JS.

So for a node-webkit app, it'd make more sense to fetch these files and store them in the Application Support folder (Or AppData, depending on the platform). That's where the node.js part is really useful, the file IO stuff.

Comment: As for node's FS complexity: Using a package like shelljs makes it much simpler for routine file stuff. Which is all it sounds like you'd need.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Sorry for delay - I didn't get an alert. I'll look into shelljs, and how to incorporate it into NodeWebkit. Simon

Comment: @SimpleSimon - Did you come to a solution in the end? What did you end up using - I have the same requirements for a project. Cheers

Comment: In the end, I built a webapp to display the images - which would only work online. I then created a php function in the CMS (Wordpress) to generate a manifest of all the pages and assets of the site. Then in Node Webkit, I created an application that would first fetch the manifest, and then download everything required to the local disk - building a duplicate file structure - then spawn a Chrome window with a file://url. Basically, cloning the website locally. It worked beautifully. I used https://github.com/mikeal/request as the method to fetch the files and write them to the local disk.